# Using map to cache the data from the sql ( with <= timestamp col in it )

Tags: java, sql, caching, collections, oracle10g

I would like to put all the data from the following sql in a map( because this sql is called many times and instead of going to db everytime ), 
 but I am wondering how to implement the <= for the timestamp

EDIT:

*I am using Oracle, just updated the tags, however, I am using PreparedStatement in java which caches queries, without being recompiled, but our program doesn't have a cache solution to cache the data from the table. going to the db and getting the data is taking 2 ms roundtrip, but getting the data from the HashMap would take a nano second. This query is being executed around 20,000 times and we would like to load all the data initially and put it inside the Hashmap.*

END OF EDIT.

```
SELECT ar   
FROM table1   
WHERE fk_col1 = ?   
AND timestamp_col <= ?   
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The way I did is as follows: but I am not sure, the timestamp_col in equals and hashCode is right. Could you suggest the modifications?

```
public class Table1Key
{
    private String fk_col1;
    private java.sql.Timestamp timestamp_col;
    //setters and getters here.
    //implementing hashCode and equals.
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((fk_col1 == null) ? 0 : fk_col1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((timestamp_col == null) ? 0 : timestamp_col.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Table1Key other = (Table1Key) obj;
        if (fk_col1 == null) {
            if (other.fk_col1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!fk_col1.equals(other.fk_col1))
            return false;
        if (timestamp_col == null) {
            if (other.timestamp_col != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!timestamp_col.equals(other.timestamp_col))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

...

```
private Map<Table1Key, String> map = Functions.getHashMapInstance();

public class Functions {
...
  public static <K,V> HashMap<K,V> getHashMapInstance() {
      return new HashMap<K,V>();
  }
}
```

---

So, I would populate the map like the following:

```
private void populateMap() throws SQLException {
      try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(table1Sql);
        ps.setFetchSize(20000);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Table1Key rdk = new Table1Key();
            String ar = rs.getString(1);
            rdk.setFk_col1(rs.getString(2));
            rdk.setTimestampCol(rs.getTimestamp(3));
            if(actualRateMap.get(rdk) == null) {
                actualRateMap.put(rdk, ar);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        ps.close();
    }
  }
```

//set the key here.

```
Table1Key tk = new Table1Key();
tk.setFk_col1(col1);
tk.setTimestampCol(timestamp);
String ar = actualRateMap.get(tk);
```

//My main concern here is .. this will work if the sql has timestamp_col = ?, but what if the timestamp_col is < than what is present in the map?

```
if(actualRate != null) {
    Logger.info("Actual Rate:"+actualRate);
}
```

Comment: @PremGenError updated the tags and question as to why we are looking for a map to store all the data eagerly.

Comment: Your code looks good, so far.  I don't see anything wrong with the hashCode and equals methods.  What are your concerns with this code?

Comment: Since, I have <= in the sql, I was wondering, if just using if `(!timestamp_col.equals(other.timestamp_col)) return false;` in the equals() is sufficient or do I have to handle that condition seperately?

Comment: Are you trying to cache your DB data in a data structure from which you will be able to easily and efficiently extract data <,>,= than the key (or some combination of the three)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap` doesn't do the job for your case, rather **[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)** can help.

a): **[RangeMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#RangeMap)** solution

Guava [RangeMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#RangeMap) is designed to handle such case:

```
//Initial RangeMap  
final RangeMap<java.sql.Timestamp, String> cache = TreeRangeMap.create();
...
String value = cache.get(thisTimestamp);
if(value == null){
     String queryFromDB = ...;//Query from DB
     cache.put(Range.atMost(thisTimestamp), queryFromDB);
     value = queryFromDB;
}
```

Of course, 'fk_coll' is problem. so you could define `Map<String/*fk_coll*/, RangeMap<java.sql.Timestamp, String>>` to handle the case.

b): **[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)** solution

```
final TreeMap<java.sql.Timestamp, String> cache = new TreeMap<>();
...
//Get least key greater than or equal to the 'thisTimestamp' 
Map.Entry<java.sql.Timestamp, String> entry = cache.ceilingEntry(thisTimestamp);
if(entry == null){
   String queryFromDB = ...;//Query from DB
   cache.put(thisTimestamp, queryFromDB);
   value = queryFromDB;
} else {
   value = entry.getValue();
}
```

and

```
HashMap<String/*fk_coll*/, TreeMap<java.sql.Timestamp, String>>
```

handles 'fk_coll'.

plus: evict is a problem in any cache case.

Comment: So, is this the only way? I can't use some comparator trickery to compare if the timestamp <= timestamp_given?

Comment: java.sql.Timestamp implements Comparable interface, so you could call Timestamp.compare().

Answer (score 0):

While HashMap does not specify the order of elements, TreeMap does. I didn't test the following code, but I guess it should work:

```
TreeMap<Timestamp, String> map = new TreeMap<Timestamp, String>(new Comparator<Timestamp>() {
    public int compare(Timestamp t1, Timestamp t2) {
       // Inverse order is required for using tailMap() as <= operator
       return t2.compareTo(t1);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This operation has not been implemented!");
    }
});
// TODO: insert data to the map
// ...

// Get the first key that is <= timestamp (remember that map is using inverse order)
TreeMap<Timestamp, String> tailMap = map.tailMap(timestamp);
Timestamp firstKey = tailMap.firstKey();
if (firstKey != null) {
  // Get the value
  String value = tailMap.get(firstKey);
}
```